# How can I create a div that moves along with the filled in progress div in a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor-blaze

I have a progress bar whose progress is calculated from out database. Essentially it knows how far in a print job its gone and displays it as a percentage (i.e. 10/20 pages printed is 50%)

I want a div to follow along with the loaded progress bar, the colored portion that shows how far along the print task has gone. Something like this.

[image]

However I am having difficulty making the tab div line up properly with the progress bar, especially when I change the screen sizes. This is how I calculate the margins and positions currently:

HTML

```
<div class="col s4 m4 l5" style="position: relative">
     <div class="left-align">PRINTING</div>
     <div id="talkbubble" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0px; margin-left: {{getTabMargin}}%">hello</div>
     <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full statusBars">
          <div class="determinate progress-dashboard-loaded" style="width: {{getprogressWidth}}%"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
getprogressWidth: function() {
   return ((progressWidth/100)*100);
},
getTabMargin: function() {
   return (((progressWidth/100)*100)-8);
},
```

This is just Blaze's way of writing javascript functions but the principle is the same. Essentially what I did was get the width of the progress bar (getprogressWidth) and then subtract 8% to compensate for the width of the div tab. However this does not work, especially when the screen is resized.

Can anyone recommend a better solution?

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: You need to offer some more code, the tiny snippets you've provided don't allow us to recreate your situation, we're missing CSS, and the majority of the JavaScript. Please take a read of the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines, hopefully they'll give enough pointers that you can improve the question to a point where it won't be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using pure css:

```
<div class="col s4 m4 l5" style="position: relative">
     <div class="left-align">PRINTING</div>
     <div class="progress progress-dashboard-full statusBars">
          <div class="determinate progress-dashboard-loaded" style="position:relative;width:50%">
            <div id="talkbubble" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: -18px;">hello</div>
          </div>   
     </div>
</div>
```